# $(window).on doesn't work as expected when migrating from jquery to zepto

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

Previously, I have a JavaScript code, which will pop up a dialog & perform redirection when user closes the browser.

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var url     = 'http://www.yahoo.com';
        var message = 'go to yahoo?';

        $('a').on('click', function() { $(window).unbind("beforeunload"); });
        $('form').on('submit', function() { $(window).unbind("beforeunload"); });

        $(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
            $(window).unbind("beforeunload");
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location = url;
            }, 0);

            return message;
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
hello world
</body>
</html>
```

I tested in chrome and it works as expected.

Now, I plan to use zepto.js instead of jquery.js for certain reason.

By changing

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="zepto.min.js"></script>
```

I realize the code no longer work. There is no JavaScript error. But, event function of `beforeunload` doesn't never triggered.

I suspect `$(window).on` behaves differently among **jquery** and **zepto**

May I know, how can I get `$(window).on("beforeunload", function() {` works for **zepto**?

Comment: You still have `jQuery`  in your code, so I would expect that there is an error that `jQuery` is not defined in the console, but you don't see it because the redirect happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the time right now to do an in deep analysis of the zepto and jquery code.

The problem is the way zepto is handling the return values of the event callback.

[mdn: beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload#Example) says that it has to be used that way:

```
e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;     // Gecko and Trident   
return confirmationMessage;              // Gecko and WebKit
```

This is done automatically by jQuery but not by Zepto.

Setting the `returnValue`  by hand seems to work fine in Chromium and Firefox:

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function(e) {
    e.returnValue = message;
    return message;
});
```

But there still might be cross-browser issues. So either you use native `addEventListener` instead of zepto or you need to do some cross browser testing.

Comment: Thanks. I tested in Edge browser and Chrome browser. Your suggested solution works fine for me.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng I was about to suggest to open an issue, but as I can see you did already ;)